# How to extract data in html in PHP from a mail from gmail API?

Tags: php, html, email, gmail-api

- I retrieve emails from GMAIL API.
- I have the content for each mail.
- I have to extract some content in this html. But this html is full of table, it doesn't have any ID's or class for the selector.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3DUTF-8">
   <meta name=3D"viewport" content=3D"width=3Ddevice-width, initial-scale=3D=  1.0">
    <meta name=3D"viewport" content=3D"width=3Ddevice-width, initial-scale=3D=  1, maximum-scale=3D1">
    </head>
    <body style=3D"font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;background-color: =  #dfdfdf;padding: 15px;margin: 0;font-size: 1px;mso-line-height-alt: 0;line-=  height: 0;mso-margin-top-alt: 1px;">
     <table style=3D"border-collapse: collapse;color: #5a5a5a;font-size: 14px;=  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;width: 100%">
      <tr style=3D"font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;text-align: left;vertica=  l-align: top;">
       <td></td>
       <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;text-al=  ign: left;vertical-align: top;width: 960px;min-width: 520px;border: 1px sol=  id #5a5a5a;padding: 20px;background: #ffffff;">
        <table style=3D"border-collapse: collapse;">
         <tr style=3D"font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;text-align: left;v=  ertical-align: top;">
          <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;v=  ertical-align: middle;">
           <table style=3D"border-collapse: collapse;width: 100%;border-=  bottom: 2px solid #ebebeb;">
            <tr>
             <td style=3D"height: 82px;text-align: center;vertical-ali=  gn: middle;font-weight: 300;font-size:32px;padding-bottom:16px;font-family:=   'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;color: #5a5a5a;">                      Email Archive Status Report                    </td>
            </tr>
           </table>
           <table style=3D"border-collapse: collapse;line-height: 21px;t=  ext-align: left;vertical-align: top;height: auto;margin: 0 20px 20px 0;">
            <tr style=3D"font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;text-align: =  left;vertical-align: top;">
             <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-size: 14px;line-height: =  21px;text-align: left;vertical-align: top;">
              <table style=3D"border-collapse: collapse;font-size: 14=  px;margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;width: 100%;">
               <tr style=3D"font-size: 14px;vertical-align: top;">
                <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Source Sa=  ns Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;text-align: left;verti=  cal-align: top;width: 50%;margin-right: 10px;">
                 <div style=3D"color: #e65f1e;border-bottom: 1px s=  olid #ebebeb;font-size: 18px;padding: 0 3px 0 3px;margin-bottom: 4px;line-h=  eight: 36px;height: 30px;margin-right: 20px;">License</div>
                 <table style=3D"border-collapse: collapse;">
                  <tr style=3D"font-size: 14px;vertical-align: to=  p;">
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: left;vertical-align: t=  op;line-height: 21px;padding-bottom:0;max-width: 270px;overflow: hidden;whi=  te-space: nowrap;padding-right: 50px;">Archives</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: left;vertical-align: t=  op;line-height: 21px;padding-bottom:0;">7 archives</td>
                  </tr>
                 </table>
                </td>
                <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Source Sa=  ns Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;text-align: left;verti=  cal-align: top;width: 50%;margin-left: 10px;">
                 <div style=3D"color: #e65f1e;border-bottom: 1px s=  olid #ebebeb;font-size: 18px;padding: 0 3px 0 3px;margin-bottom: 4px;line-h=  eight: 36px;height: 30px;margin-right: 20px;">Instance</div>
                 <table style=3D"border-collapse: collapse;">
                  <tr style=3D"font-size: 14px;vertical-align: to=  p;">
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: left;vertical-align: t=  op;line-height: 21px;padding-bottom:0;max-width: 270px;overflow: hidden;whi=  te-space: nowrap;padding-right: 50px;">Instance Name</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: left;vertical-align: t=  op;line-height: 21px;padding-bottom:0;">k477931430</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr style=3D"font-size: 14px;vertical-align: to=  p;">
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: left;vertical-align: t=  op;line-height: 21px;padding-bottom:0;max-width: 270px;overflow: hidden;whi=  te-space: nowrap;padding-right: 50px;">Version</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: left;vertical-align: t=  op;line-height: 21px;padding-bottom:0;">11.2.1.14113 (64-bit; Build Date 1/=  14/2019)</td>
                  </tr>
                 </table>
                </td>
               </tr>
              </table>
              <table style=3D"border-collapse: collapse;font-size: 14=  px;margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;width: 100%;">
               <tr style=3D"font-size: 14px;vertical-align: top;">
                <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Source Sa=  ns Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;text-align: left;verti=  cal-align: top;width: 50%;margin-right: 10px;">
                 <div style=3D"color: #e65f1e;border-bottom: 1px s=  olid #ebebeb;font-size: 18px;padding: 0 3px 0 3px;margin-bottom: 4px;line-h=  eight: 36px;height: 30px;margin-right: 20px;">Archive</div>
                 <table style=3D"border-collapse: collapse;">
                  <tr style=3D"font-size: 14px;vertical-align: to=  p;">
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: left;vertical-align: t=  op;line-height: 21px;padding-bottom:0;max-width: 270px;overflow: hidden;whi=  te-space: nowrap;padding-right: 50px;">Total Size</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: left;vertical-align: t=  op;line-height: 21px;padding-bottom:0;">538,782 messages</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr style=3D"font-size: 14px;vertical-align: to=  p;">
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: left;vertical-align: t=  op;line-height: 21px;padding-bottom:0;max-width: 270px;overflow: hidden;whi=  te-space: nowrap;padding-right: 50px;">Newly Archived 
                    <span style=3D"font-s=  ize: 10px;">(2/12/2019)</span>
                   </td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: left;vertical-align: t=  op;line-height: 21px;padding-bottom:0;">276 messages</td>
                  </tr>
                 </table>
                </td>
                <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Source Sa=  ns Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;text-align: left;verti=  cal-align: top;width: 50%;margin-left: 10px;">
                 <div style=3D"color: #e65f1e;border-bottom: 1px s=  olid #ebebeb;font-size: 18px;padding: 0 3px 0 3px;margin-bottom: 4px;line-h=  eight: 36px;height: 30px;margin-right: 20px;">Compliance</div>
                 <table style=3D"border-collapse: collapse;">
                  <tr style=3D"font-size: 14px;vertical-align: to=  p;">
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: left;vertical-align: t=  op;line-height: 21px;padding-bottom:0;max-width: 270px;overflow: hidden;whi=  te-space: nowrap;padding-right: 50px;">Service Provider Access</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: left;vertical-align: t=  op;line-height: 21px;padding-bottom:0;">Enabled</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr style=3D"font-size: 14px;vertical-align: to=  p;">
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: left;vertical-align: t=  op;line-height: 21px;padding-bottom:0;max-width: 270px;overflow: hidden;whi=  te-space: nowrap;padding-right: 50px;">Archive Access by Admin</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: left;vertical-align: t=  op;line-height: 21px;padding-bottom:0;">Enabled</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr style=3D"font-size: 14px;vertical-align: to=  p;">
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: left;vertical-align: t=  op;line-height: 21px;padding-bottom:0;max-width: 270px;overflow: hidden;whi=  te-space: nowrap;padding-right: 50px;">Retention Policies</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: left;vertical-align: t=  op;line-height: 21px;padding-bottom:0;">Total: 0 / Enabled: 0 / Automatic D=  eletion: 0</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr style=3D"font-size: 14px;vertical-align: to=  p;">
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: left;vertical-align: t=  op;line-height: 21px;padding-bottom:0;max-width: 270px;overflow: hidden;whi=  te-space: nowrap;padding-right: 50px;">Legal Hold</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: left;vertical-align: t=  op;line-height: 21px;padding-bottom:0;">Disabled</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr style=3D"font-size: 14px;vertical-align: to=  p;">
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: left;vertical-align: t=  op;line-height: 21px;padding-bottom:0;max-width: 270px;overflow: hidden;whi=  te-space: nowrap;padding-right: 50px;">Auditing</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: left;vertical-align: t=  op;line-height: 21px;padding-bottom:0;">17 event types of 28</td>
                  </tr>
                 </table>
                </td>
               </tr>
              </table>
              <table style=3D"border-collapse: collapse;font-size: 14=  px;margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;width: 100%;">
               <tr style=3D"font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;text-a=  lign: left;vertical-align: top;">
                <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Source Sa=  ns Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;text-align: left;verti=  cal-align: top;">
                 <div style=3D"color: #e65f1e;border-bottom: 1px s=  olid #ebebeb;font-size: 18px;padding: 0 3px 0 3px;margin-bottom: 4px;line-h=  eight: 36px;height: 30px;">                              Archiving Statistics 
                  <span style=3D"font-size: =  12px;">(2/12/2019)</span>
                 </div>
                 <table style=3D"border-collapse: collapse;width: =  100%;">
                  <tr style=3D"vertical-align: top;mso-line-heigh=  t-alt: 22px;line-height: 22px;">
                   <th style=3D"font-size: 14px;vertical-align: =  top;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;line-height: normal;padding: =  4px 8px;white-space: nowrap;background-color: #505050;color: #ffffff;font-w=  eight: normal;text-align: left;width: 48%;">Name</th>
                   <th style=3D"font-size: 14px;vertical-align: =  top;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;line-height: normal;padding: =  4px 8px;white-space: nowrap;background-color: #505050;color: #ffffff;font-w=  eight: normal;text-align: right;width: 11%;">Successful</th>
                   <th style=3D"font-size: 14px;vertical-align: =  top;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;line-height: normal;padding: =  4px 8px;white-space: nowrap;background-color: #505050;color: #ffffff;font-w=  eight: normal;text-align: right;width: 11%;">Failed</th>
                   <th style=3D"font-size: 14px;vertical-align: =  top;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;line-height: normal;padding: =  4px 8px;white-space: nowrap;background-color: #505050;color: #ffffff;font-w=  eight: normal;text-align: left;width: 19%;">Last Execution</th>
                   <th style=3D"font-size: 14px;vertical-align: =  top;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;line-height: normal;padding: =  4px 8px;white-space: nowrap;background-color: #505050;color: #ffffff;font-w=  eight: normal;text-align: center;width: 11%;">Last Result</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr style=3D"font-size: 14px;text-align: left;l=  ine-height: 21px;vertical-align: top;">
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: left;padding: 1px 8px;">vachonsecure.fr Charles</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: right;padding: 1px 8px;">210</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: right;padding: 1px 8px;">0</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: left;padding: 1px 8px;">2/12/2019 11:53:42 PM</td>
                   <td style=3D"font-weight: bold;color: green;f=  ont-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;=  vertical-align: top;text-align: center;padding: 0 8px;">Succeeded</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr style=3D"font-size: 14px;text-align: left;l=  ine-height: 21px;vertical-align: top;">
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: left;padding: 1px 8px;">bs-technology.fr Eric</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: right;padding: 1px 8px;">133</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: right;padding: 1px 8px;">0</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: left;padding: 1px 8px;">2/12/2019 11:48:20 PM</td>
                   <td style=3D"font-weight: bold;color: green;f=  ont-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;=  vertical-align: top;text-align: center;padding: 0 8px;">Succeeded</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr style=3D"font-size: 14px;text-align: left;l=  ine-height: 21px;vertical-align: top;">
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: left;padding: 1px 8px;">boxalacarte.com Eric</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: right;padding: 1px 8px;">244</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: right;padding: 1px 8px;">0</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: left;padding: 1px 8px;">2/12/2019 11:53:42 PM</td>
                   <td style=3D"font-weight: bold;color: green;f=  ont-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;=  vertical-align: top;text-align: center;padding: 0 8px;">Succeeded</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr style=3D"font-size: 14px;text-align: left;l=  ine-height: 21px;vertical-align: top;">
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: left;padding: 1px 8px;">pascapascal.bovero
                    <img style=3D"dis=  play: none;" />@uniic.org
                   </td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: right;padding: 1px 8px;">161</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: right;padding: 1px 8px;">0</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: left;padding: 1px 8px;">2/12/2019 11:54:10 PM</td>
                   <td style=3D"font-weight: bold;color: green;f=  ont-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;=  vertical-align: top;text-align: center;padding: 0 8px;">Succeeded</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr style=3D"font-size: 14px;text-align: left;l=  ine-height: 21px;vertical-align: top;">
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: left;padding: 1px 8px;">bs-technology.fr Info</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: right;padding: 1px 8px;">265</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: right;padding: 1px 8px;">0</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: left;padding: 1px 8px;">2/12/2019 11:59:03 PM</td>
                   <td style=3D"font-weight: bold;color: green;f=  ont-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;=  vertical-align: top;text-align: center;padding: 0 8px;">Succeeded</td>
                  </tr>
                 </table>
                </td>
               </tr>
              </table>
              <table style=3D"border-collapse: collapse;font-size: 14=  px;margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;width: 100%;">
               <tr style=3D"font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;text-a=  lign: left;vertical-align: top;">
                <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Source Sa=  ns Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;text-align: left;verti=  cal-align: top;">
                 <div style=3D"color: #e65f1e;border-bottom: 1px s=  olid #ebebeb;font-size: 18px;padding: 0 3px 0 3px;margin-bottom: 4px;line-h=  eight: 36px;height: 30px;">                              Jobs 
                  <span style=3D"font-size: 12px;">(2/12/201=  9)</span>
                 </div>
                 <table style=3D"border-collapse: collapse;">
                  <tr style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sourc=  e Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: left;line-height: 21px;v=  ertical-align: top;">
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;text-align: left;vertical-align: top;font-size: 12=  px;line-height: 16px;padding-bottom: 10px;">
                    <b>Important Notice:</b> The last result on=  ly represents the status of the job execution itself but does not necessari=  ly correspond to the result of the command executed by this job. To access =  the output of the executed command, go to 
                    <em>Administrative Tools &gt; Man=  agement API &gt; Job Results</em> in the client and double-click on the res=  pective entry.                                
                   </td>
                  </tr>
                 </table>
                 <table style=3D"border-collapse: collapse;width: =  100%;">
                  <tr style=3D"vertical-align: top;mso-line-heigh=  t-alt: 22px;line-height: 22px;">
                   <th style=3D"font-size: 14px;vertical-align: =  top;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;line-height: normal;padding: =  4px 8px;white-space: nowrap;background-color: #505050;color: #ffffff;font-w=  eight: normal;text-align: left;width: 48%;">Name</th>
                   <th style=3D"font-size: 14px;vertical-align: =  top;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;line-height: normal;padding: =  4px 8px;white-space: nowrap;background-color: #505050;color: #ffffff;font-w=  eight: normal;text-align: right;width: 11%;">Successful</th>
                   <th style=3D"font-size: 14px;vertical-align: =  top;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;line-height: normal;padding: =  4px 8px;white-space: nowrap;background-color: #505050;color: #ffffff;font-w=  eight: normal;text-align: right;width: 11%;">Failed</th>
                   <th style=3D"font-size: 14px;vertical-align: =  top;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;line-height: normal;padding: =  4px 8px;white-space: nowrap;background-color: #505050;color: #ffffff;font-w=  eight: normal;text-align: left;width: 19%;">Last Execution</th>
                   <th style=3D"font-size: 14px;vertical-align: =  top;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;line-height: normal;padding: =  4px 8px;white-space: nowrap;background-color: #505050;color: #ffffff;font-w=  eight: normal;text-align: center;width: 11%;">Last Result</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr style=3D"font-size: 14px;text-align: left;l=  ine-height: 21px;vertical-align: top;">
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: left;padding: 1px 8px;">Envoyer le rapport de statut</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: right;padding: 1px 8px;">1</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: right;padding: 1px 8px;">0</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: left;padding: 1px 8px;">2/12/2019 5:30:02 AM</td>
                   <td style=3D"font-weight: bold;color: green;f=  ont-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;=  vertical-align: top;text-align: center;padding: 0 8px;">Succeeded</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr style=3D"font-size: 14px;text-align: left;l=  ine-height: 21px;vertical-align: top;">
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: left;padding: 1px 8px;">Process Retention Policies</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: right;padding: 1px 8px;">1</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: right;padding: 1px 8px;">0</td>
                   <td style=3D"color: #5a5a5a;font-family: 'Sou=  rce Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;vertical-align: =  top;text-align: left;padding: 1px 8px;">2/12/2019 3:30:00 AM</td>
                   <td style=3D"font-weight: bold;color: green;f=  ont-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;font-size: 14px;line-height: 21px;=  vertical-align: top;text-align: center;padding: 0 8px;">Succeeded</td>
                  </tr>
                 </table>
                </td>
               </tr>
              </table>
             </td>
            </tr>
           </table>
           <div style=3D"height: 30px;border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;marg=  in: 5px;color: #999999;mso-line-height-alt: 18px;mso-margin-top-alt: 18px;l=  ine-height: 18px;font-size: 11px;">
            <div style=3D"text-align: left;">
             <span style=3D"font-size: 11px;mso-line-height-alt: 18px;=  line-height: 18px;mso-margin-top-alt: 18px;color: #5a5a5a;text-align: left;=  vertical-align: top;font-family: 'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif;">&nbsp;
             </spa=  n>
            </div>
           </div>
          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
       </td>
       <td></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </body>
```

In this string, I would like to extract some data like emails, and date.   This is not the most complex things in here. All the mails address are not like

```
"johndoe@gmail.com"
```

it can be, but most of the mail address is like

```
xxx.fr Charles
```

Firstly I tried to extract the html, and after with the XPath retrieve the content I want. But the problem is when I'm selecting only "//tr", how do I know which string is an address, the other is a location or whatever

Here's my code:

```
            $message_id = $lm->id;
            $thread_id = $lm->threadId;
            $optParamsGet2['format'] = 'raw';
            $single_message = $gmail->users_messages->get('me', $message_id, $optParamsGet2);
            $body = base64url_decode($single_message->raw);
            $string = preg_replace('~[[:cntrl:]]~', " ", $body);
            $rawString = strip_tags(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string));

            $html = get_string_between($string, "<!DOCTYPE html>", "</html>");

            libxml_use_internal_errors(true) AND libxml_clear_errors();
            $doc = new DOMDocument();
            $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
            $doc->loadHTML($html);

            $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
            $nodes = $xpath->query("//tr");
```

Do you have some pieces of advice?

EDIT:

I tried the @Anthony Harley's solution, this is the result [link](https://pastebin.com/bttQ5cnt). I use regex to extract the begin, but for the adress, i couldn't. In the Index 10 of the table, i want to extract the name, the date and if it succeed. But its not the same pattern for each user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to your script based on our comment chain. You'd definitely have an easier time keeping this as a DOMDocument. However, you weren't converting your email from quoted printable, which may be why you're using DomXPath. The code below prints the 5 records from the table and the pattern could be used to get data from any other table. At this point, it'd be up to you about how to handle the emails in that field. Hope this helps!

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$file = quoted_printable_decode(file_get_contents('test.html'));
$doc->loadHTML($file);

$records = [];

$tables = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table');
$emailTable = $tables->item(10);

$rows = $emailTable->getElementsByTagName('tr');

for($i = 2; $i < $rows->length; $i++) {
    $row = $rows->item($i);
    $cells = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');

    $records[] = [
        'Email' => $cells->item(0)->nodeValue
    ];
}

var_dump($records);
?>
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply. I edited my question, with your help.

Comment: Just saw your reply. How many patterns are there and are there any identifiers in the row you can use to collect? Seems like the only thing to watch out for is the img tag in some td's unless I'm missing something else.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply and ur time. for the first indexes, we have a pattern, we can extract the data. But for the index 10 for example, we can't. https://pastebin.com/raw/0W12KH6s
I want to extract for the first row "boxalacarte.com Eric", but it can be "eric@boxalacarte.com" or it can be a simply strings at this position ...

Comment: Edited my comment with a possible solution

Comment: Did you have any luck with my new answer?

Comment: I tried this morning, your answer help me to find the email ;) thks a lot

Comment: No problem, make sure you upvote the answer in case it could help anyone else out. Happy coding!

Answer (score -2):

You should use arrays for this because those are easy and clear.
I will give an example so you can use it to create your own code because the code isn't really clear, but I still want to be so kind to provide an answer.

I will explain how arrays work, in case you aren't familiar with arrays.

You can create an array like this:

```
    <?php
    $array = array(
   "variable1" => "someemail@address.com",
   "variable2" => "foo",
    );
    ?>
```

They can be an integer or a string.

When you want to retrieve it you can use:

```
<?php
echo "Email:";
echo $variable1;
?>
```

I hoped I explained the basics well and I hope you can use this.